# using pgfmathanglebetweenlines newbie question

Tags: pgfmath, syntax

I've just started to use tikz and I want to use `\pgfmathanglebetweenlines`, but I'm obviously not understanding it. I was expecting the following code to report the angle in the `\try` parameters, but it comes out as 0<sup>o</sup> each time (or sometimes 45<sup>o</sup> each time or 90<sup>o</sup>each time). What have I done wrong?

```
%
% preamble
%
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
%
% drawing.
%
\begin{document}
\def\try#1{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate[label=below:$O$](O)at(0,0);
\coordinate[label=$X$](X)at(1,0);
\coordinate[label=$Y$](Y)at({cos(#1)},{sin(#1)});
\draw(Y)--(O)--(X);
\pgfmathanglebetweenlines{(O)}{(Y)}{(O)}{(X)}                                                                
\coordinate[label=right:{$\angle YOX=\pgfmathresult^\circ$}](label)at(X);             
\end{tikzpicture}
\\} 
\try{20}\try{45}\try{60}\try{180}\try{405}\try{-45}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here. Firstly, `\pgfmathanglebetweenlines` requires basic layer coordinate specifications (e.g., in this case `\pgfpointanchor{Y}{center}`). Secondly `\pgfmathresult` is redefined every time the mathematical engine is used so by the time it is typeset the angle measurement is lost.

A solution is shown below. Note I have also added in a correction for acute angles (I think the documentation for `\pgfmathanglebetweenlines` isn't quite right) and to get the angle rounded to the nearest integer.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\try#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate[label=below:$O$] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=$X$]       (X) at (1,0);
\coordinate[label=$Y$]       (Y) at (cos #1, sin #1);
\draw (Y) -- (O) -- (X);
\pgfmathanglebetweenlines%
  {\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Y}{center}}
  {\pgfpointanchor{O}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{X}{center}}
\pgfmathparse{int(round(min(\pgfmathresult, 360-\pgfmathresult))}% Correction
\let\angleyox=\pgfmathresult                                                              
\coordinate [label=right:{$\angle YOX=\angleyox^\circ$}] (label) at (X);             
\end{tikzpicture}
\\}
\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {20, 45, 60, 180, 405,-45}{\try{\a}}
\end{document}
```

But! The basic layer stuff isn't necessary. The `calc` library provides all the stuff you need:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\try#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\coordinate[label=below:$O$] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=$X$]       (X) at (1,0);
\coordinate[label=$Y$]       (Y) at (cos #1, sin #1);
\draw (Y) -- (O) -- (X);
\path let \p1=(O),\p2=(Y),\p3=(X),
   \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},
   \n2={atan2(\y3-\y1,\x3-\x1)} in
   node at (X) [right] {\pgfmathparse{int(abs(\n2-\n1))}% Correction
     $\angle YOX=\pgfmathresult^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\}
\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {20, 45, 60, 180, 405,-45}{\try{\a}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer. The documentation of \pgfmathanglebetweenlines errs as you note. It should read "anticlockwise" rather than "clockwise", so X and Y should have been interchanged in the macro call. I have added \def\pb#1{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}} to my standard preamble so, hopefully, I'll now also be able to successfully use the shift parameter in \pgftransformcm. I notice that without the correction applied the printed results can differ by a value < 0.06. Is this just a matter of the limits of accuracy in arithmetical calculations?

Comment: By the way how did you get the result to display on the page?